# "=" sign in JSON text causes parsing error

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, equals, sign

```
      "Cost to Implement \nRate 5 to 1\nHigh = 5\nLow = 1"
```

as part of a JSON parses fine in jsonlint, but fails in Chrome with any of  these approaches (each tried separately):

```
sections = $.parseJSON(myJSONstr);

sections = JSON.parse(myJSONstr);

sections = eval('(' + myJSONstr + ')');
```

When I remove the "=" signs from the string in the JSON, all is fine.  My users will need the ability to enter the = sign in the text they enter.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: how are you setting `myJSONst`, if the string you provided wasn't escaped properly it won't parse correctly.

Comment: @pst, don't use `eval` for parsing JSON.

Comment: The JSON string was created by entering text into textarea elements, saving those strings into a class object, then JSON.stringify to create the JSON.  The \n entered in the textarea elements appear to save as \n in the JSON.

Comment: yes - using eval was just an experiment, or a frustrated shot-in-the-dark more accurately.  Thank you

Comment: Could you provide that interaction in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Describing what you're trying to do isn't as good as seeing how you tried to do it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GettingToOld/P4LkS/2/

Comment: And, in the process of building it, figured out that copying the JSON string from the console, the console had already stripped the escape characters.  Thanks for your help

Comment: The console doesn't display strings in a way that can be safely used as a literal. It's just a convenient way of checking the values that JS variables resolve to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are entering the newline without escaping it. You need to escape the backslashes.

The following fails because you're entering a raw newline into the JSON, they must be escaped

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"prop": "Cost to Implement \nRate 5 to 1\nHigh = 5\nLow = 1"}');
```

Escape the backslashes

```
// Works fine
var obj = JSON.parse('{"prop": "Cost to Implement \\nRate 5 to 1\\nHigh = 5\\nLow = 1"}');
```

Note that these new lines (and other characters that must escaped like tabs, backspaces...) will be automatically escaped if you correctly serialize your JSON objects. For example

```
// Correctly parses the new line
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({prop: "Line1\nLine2\tAfterTab"}))
```

Comment: Thank you - that now works.  It looks like the saved JSON only saves \n, and that I will need to search the JSON prior to parsing to replace \n with \\n in order for it to parse correctly.  True?  Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: @GettingToOld, you shouldn't have to do a replace to encode your data as JSON, otherwise you'll end up with all sorts of other encoding errors such as `\f`, `\r`, `\t`, etc. Please show what code you're using to generate the string, which is probably where the issue lies.

Comment: You should not search for `\n`. You need to use a JSON encoder like `JSON.stringify` which will handle the new lines and all the other characters that must be escaped for JSON. Try the following `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({prop: "Line1\nLine2"}))`

Comment: I'll try and figure out how to create a fiddle of the problem.  I have a class (myClass) with many properties, including a string property for storing the contents of a textarea.  I use $(...).val() to return the value of the textarea to myBigArray[n].myStrProperty, then use JSON.stringify(myBigArray).  So, myBigArray is an array of many myClass objects.  The JSON.stringify creates the "this text\nhas\nmany\nlinefeeds" string, exactly as I typed, as part of the JSON.  Using Chrome and Jquery.  I'll work on the fiddle now

Comment: Built the fiddle, and it all worked - and that's when the light bulb, rather dimly, lit...  I was copying the JSON string from the console, which had already stripped the escape characters in front of the newlines.  As my user name says...

Comment: @GettingToOld Then please mark this as the accepted answer by clicking the tick mark next to the vote count